# Why is this recursive addition wrong in Scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

```
#lang eopl

(define (vectorSum V b e)    ; b is starting index, and e is ending index
  (cond
    [ (eqv? b e) vector-ref V b]
    [ (> b e)
      (eopl:error 'vectorSum "starting index must be smaller than or equal to the end index")]
    [ else (+ (vector-ref V b) (vectorSum V (+ b 1) e))]))


(define A #(1 1 1 1 1))
```

When I try this, I am getting the wrong result. What's the problem here?

```
> (vectorSum A 0 4)
8
> (vectorSum A 0 1)
2
> (vectorSum A 0 3)
6
> (vectorSum A 1 3)
5
> (vectorSum A 1 2)
3

> (vectorSum A 0 1)
2
> (vectorSum A 1 2)
3
```

Take (vectorSum A 0 3), when I expanded the recursion, I thought it was supposed to be

```
+ 1 + VectorSum (1 3)
    + 1 + VectorSum (2, 3)
        + 1 + VectorSum (3, 3)
            + 1   (I hit the first case, there is no more recursion)
= 4
```

Instead, I get 6. Why?

Thanks.

---

Look at 0,1 and 1,2 the answers aren't equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer should look like this:

```
(define (vectorSum V b e)
  (cond ((eqv? b e)
         (vector-ref V b))
        ((> b e)
         (eopl:error 'partialVectorSum "starting index must be smaller than or equal to the end index"))
        (else (+ (vector-ref V b) (vectorSum V (+ b 1) e)))))
```

It was a simple mistake - you forgot a couple of parenthesis in this line:

```
[ (eqv? b e) vector-ref V b]
```

It should have been:

```
[ (eqv? b e) (vector-ref V b) ]
```

Without those parenthesis, you're not actually calling the `vector-ref` procedure, instead you're listing some symbols and returning the final one, `b` in this case. Remember to always surround a procedure call and its arguments between parenthesis, just as you did in the `else` part.

Comment: So the main cause was really the lack of parenthesis around the vector-ref in the first condition. How does that cause problem? How can I trace this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Without those parenthesis, you're not actually _calling_ the `vector-ref` procedure, instead you're listing some symbols and returning the final one, `b` in this case. How to trace it? I can't think of a way to detect this kind of error (besides visual inspection), just remember to surround a procedure call and its arguments between parenthesis, just as you did in the `else` part.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of how the recursion unfolds is correct. Your problem is that you forgot to parenthesize your call to `vector-ref` in the first case. The way you wrote it `vector-ref V b` is interpreted as three independent expressions. The last of which (`b`) is the value of the expression. So since in your example `b` is 3, you'll get `1 + 1 + 1 + 3 = 6`.

Simply add the parentheses to make it a function call, and it will work like you want it to.

Comment: Ahh. Now I get it. Took me 20 mins bugging why. It's always good to ask on stackoverflow! You guys rock!